# getting class name of check box when it checked

Tags: javascript

I have html code like this having a class name:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="ques11" name="radiobutton" class="option_1" />
```

and I also have another line

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="ques12" name="radiobutton" class="option_2" />
```

If I check the first check box, I want to get the class name of that check box as the output, and to store it in a script variable. How do I get this class name?

Comment: *"...and also i have another line..."* Then you have invalid HTML. You can't use the same `id` value (`ques11`) on more than one element.

Comment: `$(this).closest("input[id^='ques']").attr('class').split('_')` this will return an array of string.. so adding .val() would result to an error

Comment: i have changed the code please find it

Comment: i have updated new code please find it ,help me

Comment: @tatapudivenugopal: It's not okay to change the question so that existing answers are no longer valid. I've rolled back the edit. If you can add more information to the question **without** invalidating existing answers, great, but even looking at the edit it's unclear why the below doesn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

From within a click handler attached using jQuery (or several other ways), `this` **is** a reference to the `input`, you don't need `closest`.

That isn't your problem, though, your problem is trying to call `val` on an array. If you want the second entry in the array from `split`, just use `[1]`:

```
var quesNo = this.className.split("_")[1];
```

Note that this assumes there is only a single class on the `input`.

---

Rather than using a class name for this, though, I suggest using a `data-*` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="ques11" name="radiobutton" data-quesno="" />
```

then

```
var quesNo = $(this).attr("data-quesno");
```

(You'll get people telling you to use `.data("quesno")` instead. Only do that if you need the features [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) provides. It is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes, that's a common misconception.)

Comment: @Phil: Re your suggested edit: ***No***, see the note at the end of the answer (which your edit would have removed because you overlapped it and ignored the warning).